# Sitename alternate suggestion SEO

Tags: seo, html, google-search

I had a question about SEO.

Say, I've made a restaurant website, which is running for a while now. I added some titles, meta tags, keywords,description,etc,etc on it's pages.

Now, let's say for example the name is fudeg.com.

When I google for fudeg, it gives me results for fudge instead. Now, when I click on "search for fuedge instead" my site does appear.

So how do i get my site entry in google for fudge?
Do i add fudge in the description,keywords and other related SEO tags as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that your site isn't being recognized. It's that Google thinks the name is a [misspelling](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/answer.py?answer=1723). It's completely automated and basically you're stuck with it. I would guess that if the system sees enough search volume for your term, something might start letting the word through, but I haven't seen a specific statement about that.

The only way I'm aware of to force the exact term is to quote it(search for `"fudeg"` rather than just `fudeg`), but that's obviously not practical for random people who might be looking for you.

Answer (score 2):

As with anything related to Google, you *probably* could overcome this by building up a significant amount of quality backlinks to your pages (not just the home page) over time. Eventually this might elevate "fudeg" to be considered a "real word" and to show results for it (although I suspect Google will still show "did you mean fudge" when displaying those search results).

As for ranking well for "fudge", simply adding meta tags and other "SEO tags" are not going to help you. Your pages are not about fudge and thus will not rank well for searches for "fudge" and rightfully so.